# rendering a list of components in ngFor angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of `IAnimal` with components like dog cat each has its own properties and extends the `IAnimal` Interface.

Now I want to render all the components in a `*ngFor` loop from my `IAnimal` Array how do I do that?
looking for something like `DataTemplate` in xaml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thanks for your link looks like the right answer. but for some odd reason I'm getting an error `No component factory found for [object Object]`

Comment: Perhaps you didn't list the dynamically added component(s) in `@NgModule({entryComponents: [...]})`?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer yes I did..

Comment: You might have passed the component type using `{{myDynamicComponent}}`. It needs to be `[prop]="myDynamicComponent"`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I got my mistake I added to the array a `new myDynamicComponent()`. thanks anyway